# Clarification regarding reference to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I was trying to pass **reference to pointers**, mainly two cases:

1. `const int* &ref_var` - **ref_var** being a reference to a pointer to a constant integer.
2. `int *const &ref_var` - **ref_var** being a reference to a constant pointer to an integer.

Now the second case works fine since I cannot modify the pointer itself, but in 1st case I am receiving an error message which I don't think should be there since a *non-const* pointer variable can be passed as argument to a function with *constant* pointer as parameter.

**code:**

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void fun(const int* &ref_var)  //error: invalid initialization of reference of type const int*& from expression of type int*
{
     //BLANK
}

int main()
{
    int x=9;
    int *p=&x;     //ERROR VANISHES IF P IS DECLARED AS POINTER TO CONSTANT INT         
    fun(p);
    return 0; 
}
```

Where as when the function `fun` is declared as:

```
void fun(const int *ptr)
{
     //BLANK
}
```

It works fine despite the argument passed being *non-const* pointer to int.

Could you please tell me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different types and a pointer to an `int` is not a pointer to a `const int`. Yes, a pointer to an `int` can be cast to a pointer to a `const int`.

The issue here is that there is an additional indirection level, the reference. So you have a reference to a `int*`. The target is different that a reference to a `const int*`.

It's similar than having a `char*`, getting a pointer to it and trying to pass it to a `const char**`. It will also fail because the inner types are different.

And yes, it can be annoying. The only option is setting the proper type before getting a reference to it, so `p` must be a `const int*`.